# Python - Working out how many boxes can fit in a space

Tags: python

I was looking at making a program that can accurately work out how many boxes could fill a space without ever overflowing that space.

So, what i've done is create a dict list that has a product and it's set dimensions (all of these are in cm)

Then i've linked 3 different sizes (width, length and height) and gave them their values so i can have the program then check back and see if these values are surpassed and if so, stop adding boxes. As soon as 1 value has been breached, no more can be added. (Except for possibly height, because you could go another level higher on the pallet, but that's too complex for me at the moment).

So now that i've wrote it out, i'm sat starting at this screen thinking, "right, where do i start off." I'm not looking for definitive answers, but this is my first proper attempt at writing a program and i'd a "nudge" in the right direction. What should i tackle first and how would be best to approach that, etc. etc.

Current code:

```
products = {'a':[60, 100, 20]}

palletL = 120
palletW = 100
palletH = 200

def add(a, b, c):
    return a+b+c
```

Comment: Are you aware that this is a well-known class of algorithm? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem

Comment: I wasn't. Hence the statement "this is my first ever proper project".

Comment: Well, now you know! Sorry you're getting a very negative response from people on your second question. You can try reading up on the algorithms, attempt a bit more code and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to solve a optimization problem.

In your example there is only one box "a", but I assume you want to have multiple boxes with lengths. Then you want to have a container with fixed length also, and you want the answer like: a, b and c can be placed in container without overflow. Is it right?

If yes you should read about [knapsnack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem).

Read also related [articles](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/20569/dynamic-programming-solution-to-knapsack-problem) about possible [implementations](https://sites.google.com/site/mikescoderama/Home/0-1-knapsack-problem-in-p).